# Azure Storage Emulator 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I'm suddenly getting the Bad Request (400) error when using the Azure Storage Emulator when trying to CreateIfNotExists. The Response on the Inner Exception says "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format." All the tables exist, the data is in the tables, everything was working up until an update to my NuGet packages. Looking around SO it seems like a common cause is an update to Azure Storage Client Library (now at 5.0.0) that creates a mismatch. I updated the Azure SDK to 2.6 (since I have VS2012). This brings the Storage Emulator up to 4.0.0.0, but still no luck...same error. This is kind of a bad thing that suddenly an update to a package of a package of a package causes the whole thing to break and completely kills my rather large project. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Storage Client library are you using in your project?

Comment: 5.0.0 I also tried the new pre-release but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is a problem for anyone else, but this is what I have figured out...

- Storage Emulator 4.1.0.0 is the one to use with Azure Storage Client Library 5.0.0
- Storage Emulator 4.1.0.0 comes with Azure SDK 2.7.
- Azure SDK 2.7 will not work with Visual Studio 2012.
- Azure SDK 2.6 for VS2012 has Emulator 4.0.0.0. I don't know what Storage Client Library is compatible... I tried 4.3.0.0, 5.0.0.0, and 5.0.2, but had no luck

.

My "philosophical" issues with this whole thing are...

- I can find no discernible connection between Storage Emulator
  versions and Storage Client Library versions....The numbers don't
  "match"; there are no errors, dependencies, or exceptions that tell
  you the relationship; I can't find any look-up, cross-reference, or
  table that describes the proper combination of libraries.
- The "just use the latest version" theory doesn't work because in the
  past they have released new versions of the Storage Client library
  (3.0.0.0) w/o a working Emulator and now the "latest version" of each
  is separately dependent on which SDK is available for your build
  environment (VS2012 vs VS2015)

I understand the Storage Client Library isn't technically "dependent" on the emulator...you don't need the emulator to use Azure Storage. However, it would just be nice if some of these relationships were a little easier for a software oaf like me to figure out.

Comment: Looks like Storage Client Library 6.0.0 is using the 2015-04-05 version of the REST API, which is only supported in emulator version 4.2.

Comment: Someone else having the exact same problem and the response from the Azure Team here https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/183 is to upgrade to storage emulator version 4.2.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the problem was with the **Container Name**, which has strict naming requirements.

Namely:

> - Only **lowercase** letters, numbers, and dash are allowed
> - Must be 3 to 63 characters

For more information, view [Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd135715.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I got this issue upon upgrading to the currently latest `WindowsAzure.Storage version 9.3.1` package.

After hours of trying out various combinations of container names, and other stuff, the simplest solution was to roll back to the older and working `version 8.6.0`!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you would need to downgrade client libraries to 4.x as well.

You see, each version of storage client library corresponds to a storage service REST API version and same goes for storage emulator as well. If you use storage emulator version 4.0, then you can't use storage client library 5 with that. You would need to use version 4.x with that.

If you want to use storage client library version 5, then you have 2 options:

1. Make use of latest version of storage emulator or
2. Do your development against cloud storage account.

Comment: The Storage Emulator is part of Azure SDK. If you have VS2012, then the SDK is 2.6. The Storage Emulator for 2.6 is 4.0.0.0. The latest Storage Client Library is 5.0.0. So you're saying you have to update to SDK 2.7 (and therefore VS2015) to get a version of Emulator that works with Client Library 5.0.0.0? That seems like a bad back door to force people to upgrade Visual Studio without them knowing it.

Comment: Yes. To make use of latest version of storage emulator, you would need latest SDK (2.7) which is supported on both VS 2013 and 2015 (no VS 2012 though unfortunately).

Comment: In addition, downgrading the Storage Client Library to 4.3.0.0 (to "match" my Emulator 4.0.0) doesn't work either. No exceptions, just every call returns a silent "false".