# Cannot create queue/container in Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I have a very simple console project with the following code:

```
        // NOTE: We piggyback on web jobs storage for now
        var connString = AmbientConnectionStringProvider.Instance
            .GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringNames.Storage);

        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
        var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(InputQueueName);
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

When I try to run it locally against the Azure Storage Emulator (I am using version 4.3), I get a 404 Not Found "The specified queue does not exist." exception thrown from the `CreateIfNotExists` line.
If I manually create the queue in Visual Studio Cloud Explorer (under the (Development) storage account), this code works.
When I use an actual storage account in Azure, the code works.

The same thing happens with blob containers.

I have deleted the localdb database and recreated. The init command runs without errors.

Any ideas?

#### EDIT

The connection string ending up in connString variable is `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"`.

#### EDIT2

I am using version 7.0.0 of the NuGet package WindowsAzure.Storage.

Comment: What's the connection string passed into CloudStorageAccount.Parse()?

Comment: What's the version of Azure Storage Client Library being used? It should be lower than or equal to the version of Azure Storage Emulator (v4.3 as you mentioned).

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft Aha, that might be the problem then. I had assumed that the version was fine since I didn't get 400 Bad Request like others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322029/azure-storage-emulator-400-bad-request.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft So, is that a dependable rule? That version of client library needs to be lower or equal to the emulator? Because such a rule would be extremely nice to have and should be made widely known.

Comment: Actually the exact rule should be: the REST API version used by storage client library must be supported by the storage emulator. To find out the information, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/#storage-emulator-release-notes , https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/README.md .

Comment: Unluckily this is not the root cause for your case, since storage client library 7.0 is supported by storage emulator 4.3.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator? Often, errors like this come from forgetting that :)

Comment: @PedroG.Dias I am certainly not running VS as administrator, what a security hole that would be! I did, however, run the storage emulator as administrator :)

Comment: Well, sometimes you have to. In order for VS to be able to run things on your behalf that uses ports, you need to let it run as admin. Not really a security hole unless your computer is horribly configured :)