# Azure Storage Emulator - (400) Bad Request - HTTP headers is not in the correct format

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to perform some simple actions with the Azure storage emulator and consistently encounter the exception "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." Going into RequestInformation>ExtendedErrorInformation I also see "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format."

This is an example of code that fails:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

container.CreateIfNotExists(); // This is where it fails
```

I have found some cases where this might be a [SDK version issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322029/azure-storage-emulator-400-bad-request).  I am running Visual Studio 2012. I have installed [version 2.6 of Azure SDK for .NET](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46892), since this is the last supported version of VS 2012.

Based on the simplicity of the code, I imagine this is an issue with the environment. I am very new to working with Azure, so I wouldn't be surprised if there is something minor I am missing. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of storage client library are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.0.0.0.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322029/azure-storage-emulator-400-bad-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest version of the Storage Emulator. You can get the latest Storage Emulator as a standalone installer (not part of the SDK) at the [Azure Download](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) page under "Command line tools".

Comment: I am using version 5.10.0 and I get this error. I have the latest version and I am using Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob when the error occurs copying blobs from azure to local

Comment: @johnstaveley having the same issue. Any chance you got this figured out?

Comment: I have updated to the latest emulator and storage explorer and I am using the new MS authentication library in options. Not sure if this fixed it or not though