# CosmosDB Emulator: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-emulator

I am writing/debugging an Azure Function with the Azure Storage Emulator on my local machine. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure which API(s) I should use or the correct URLs for the storage. My code looks like this:

```csharp
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(storageURL, authKeyString);
Database db = client.GetDatabase("devstoreaccount1");
container = db.GetContainer("leaderboard");
ItemResponse<StoredScore> resp = await container.CreateItemAsync<StoredScore>(newScore);
```

The inputs to the function are:

```
storageURL = "http://127.0.0.1:10002"
authKeyString = "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
```

On the last line of the code above, I get an exception:

```
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : initializeTask failed Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidHeaderValue</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:ed82efd8-6cb8-4a2e-a793-16a38b3c8f2a
Time:2019-12-20T20:07:19.9539313Z</message>
</error>
RequestUri: http://127.0.0.1:10002/;
RequestMethod: GET;
Header: x-ms-version Length: 10;
Header: User-Agent Length: 98;
Header: x-ms-date Length: 29;
Header: Authorization Length: 84;
, Request URI: /, RequestStats: , SDK: Windows/10.0.16299 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.4.2
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayStoreClient.ParseResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, DocumentServiceRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.GetDatabaseAccountAsync(Uri serviceEndpoint)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager.GetDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync(Uri defaultEndpoint, IList`1 locations, Func`2 getDatabaseAccountFn)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.InitializeReaderAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosAccountServiceConfiguration.InitializeAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.InitializeGatewayConfigurationReaderAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.GetInitializationTaskAsync(IStoreClientFactory storeClientFactory)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.EnsureValidClientAsync()
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code BadRequest, message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidHeaderValue</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:67e1f70a-c9c8-4aed-892c-964e8ff0f0e1
Time:2019-12-20T20:11:28.0006476Z</message>
</error>
RequestUri: http://127.0.0.1:10002/;
RequestMethod: GET;
Header: x-ms-version Length: 10;
Header: User-Agent Length: 98;
Header: x-ms-date Length: 29;
Header: Authorization Length: 82;
, inner exception: null, and response headers: {
"Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
"x-ms-request-id": "67e1f70a-c9c8-4aed-892c-964e8ff0f0e1",
"Date": "Fri, 20 Dec 2019 20:11:27 GMT",
}
DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Fail to reach global gateway http://127.0.0.1:10002/, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>InvalidHeaderValue</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:67e1f70a-c9c8-4aed-892c-964e8ff0f0e1
Time:2019-12-20T20:11:28.0006476Z</message>
</error>
RequestUri: http://127.0.0.1:10002/;
RequestMethod: GET;
Header: x-ms-version Length: 10;
Header: User-Agent Length: 98;
Header: x-ms-date Length: 29;
Header: Authorization Length: 82;
, Request URI: /, RequestStats: , SDK: Windows/10.0.16299 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.4.2
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayStoreClient.ParseResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, DocumentServiceRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.GetDatabaseAccountAsync(Uri serviceEndpoint)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager.GetDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync(Uri defaultEndpoint, IList`1 locations, Func`2 getDatabaseAccountFn)
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

The Azure Storage Emulator is running and I can manipulate it in Storage Explorer.

Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong? Am I using the 'best' API for this?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the emulator is running at 127.0.0.1:10002? [This question and its answers may also help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322029/azure-storage-emulator-400-bad-request)

Comment: This may be a stupid question but why are you calling Storage with Cosmos DB classes?

Comment: Ian, if the emulator weren't at that URL, I wouldn't  be getting back a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you want to use cosmosdb to store your `StoredScore` data. If so , you should use CosmosDB emulator on your side instead of storage Emulator.

Pls follow steps below to make your code work :

1. [Install and run CosmosDB emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#installation)
2. Create a cosmos db with a collection on your local :

[image]

In this case , my cosmos db name is `localdb` and my container name is `localcontainer`

You can find your cosmosdb host and key here : 
[image]

3.Create a http trigged Azure function in VS locally, this is my code below :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

namespace cosmostest
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081/", "<your key here>");
            Database db = client.GetDatabase("<your local db name>");
            Container container = db.GetContainer("<your local container name>");
            var newScore = new StoredScore() { id ="1", name ="stan", score =100 };
            ItemResponse<StoredScore> resp = await container.CreateItemAsync<StoredScore>(newScore);
            return new OkObjectResult(resp.StatusCode);
        }
    }

    public class StoredScore
    {

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Run the function and trigger it, if you get "201" as response, your data has been saved into you local cosmos DB successfully :
[image]

Data in local cosmos DB:
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep. I confused the Storage Emulator and the Cosmos DB emulator. Thank you.